# discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "ABCMeta" failed for parameter "member". Discord Change Nickname command error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def nickmod(ctx, arg,member=discord.Member):
    await member.edit(nick=arg)
    await ctx.send(f"""{member.mention}'s nicknamed has been modified""")
```

This is my current code for a command that changes your nickname. I must have done something wrong with my code because everytime I try to use it, it returns this error in the console

`"discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "ABCMeta" failed for parameter "member".`

I hope someone can help me, I've never faced this kind of error before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[discord.py converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) use the type hinting syntax, `argument: converter`. I would write your command like this:

```
@client.command()
async def nickmod(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, new_name):
    await member.edit(nick=new_name)
    await ctx.send(f"""{member.mention}'s nicknamed has been modified""")
```

Here I also use the [Keyword-Only Arguments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments) syntax to allow for nicknames with spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate this :>